# Clarification on how to calculate the density of states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-of-states

I'm a little confused on how this works. The question asks to calculate the density of states $$\nu(E) = \int_0^{\infty}dp\,\delta(E-E_p)$$ where $$E_p = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$

This should be simple right? For some reason I'm having difficulty understanding how to do this. Any clarification is appreciated!

Comment: You need to express $\mathrm{d}p$ in terms of $\mathrm{d}E_p$ then you have it due to the [properties of $\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

Answer (score 0):

The specific property of delta functions that you are looking for is
$$\int dx \;\delta(f(x)) = \sum \frac{1}{|f'(x)|}$$

where the sum is over all roots of $f(x)$ that lie within the range of integration.

Henceforth, in this case, the final answer you are expecting is
$$\nu(E) = \sqrt{\frac{m}{2E}}$$
I would leave for you to work it out.

Knowing this property would help you calculate the density of states in any case, no matter how complicated your $E_p$ is.